# Reverse sort divs using CSS or jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <span>Fe</span>
        <span>Fi</span>
        <span>Fo</span>
        <span>Fum</span>
    </div>


    <div>
        <span>He</span>
        <span>Hi</span>
        <span>Ho</span>
        <span>Hum</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I would like the inner divs to display in reverse order like so:

He Hi Ho Hum
Fee Fi Fo Fum

Comment: You're example result doesn't really reverse the sort order. It just swaps the order of the two `<div>` elements. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Patrick: Yes, that is what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: Alright, I [posted an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062630/reverse-sort-divs-using-css-or-jquery/6062732#6062732) that does that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var first = $('div > div:first-child');

first.appendTo(first.parent());
```

---

**EDIT:** To deal with several elements, you can do this:

```
$('div > div').each(function() {
    $(this).prependTo(this.parentNode);
});
```

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/xB4sB/

Comment: This is the simplest and most generic version offered. Thanks!

Comment: Can this be generalized even further so that if there were 3 or 4 divs that they would be listed in reverse order?

Comment: @user113716 Do you know if this will work with ordered list elements, without changing their numeric value?

Answer (score 2):

One method is:

```
$('div span:contains("He")').parent().insertBefore('div > div:eq(0)');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MmFsM/).

Conversely, you could also just CSS to simulate the 'reversed' order:

```
div > div {
    width: 48%;
    float: right;
}

div > div:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #ffa;
}

div > div:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #0f0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MmFsM/1/).

References:

- [`:contains-selector()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Comment: Your jQuery solution works visually, but I'm pretty sure OP wants to keep them in the same outer div. Currently it is placing it outside the outer. You'd need to change the selector to `.insertBefore('div:eq(1)')` or `.insertBefore('div > div:eq(0)')` or use `.prependTo('div:eq(0)')`.

Comment: @patrick dw: thanks! That's what I meant to do, but completely forgot that they were contained...sigh. **Must** read more slowly and carefully... **edited**

Answer (score 1):

You could swap the two nodes [using this method](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2008/9/24/A-quick-and-dirty-swap-method-for-jQuery). Here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uy4UA/). Also you probably could give them unique id names to simplify the selectors.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$($("span").remove().toArray().reverse()).appendTo("div");
```

Answer (score 0):

give each div an id and use insertBefore. Example:

```
$('#hehihohum').insertBefore('#fefifofum');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aJkXj/)

Comment: I like your avatar, Home Movies is fantastic.