# jQuery/JavaScript or CSS how to Re-Arrrange controls from Left To Right to Right To Left Layout?

Tags: c#, asp.net, right-to-left

Greetings to everyone,

I have some reports made in ASP.NET with ActiveReports, I have over 500 reports that are in English, I want to change the layout of the reports from Left To Right (English) to Right To Left (Hebrew/Arabic Languages)

For example, lets say a report has the following columns:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
```

I want to change the layout of the page so that the columns are rearranged in reverse order:

```
Column5 Column4 Column3 Column2 Column1
```

It's as if I'm looking at the page through a mirror.

Is it possible to do this  using jQuery or JavaScript or even CSS? If so can you give me some hints? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more information. How are you displaying your reports? using GridView controls? if so, can you provide a sample HTML

Answer (score 2):

Eric

In order to make the columns appear differently, the reports will need to be re-designed to right to left display.  You can either do it in using the ActiveReports Designer or in Visual Studio.  It is also possible to update the layout by using API and then save the report back out.

I would be curious to know how jq or js will accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS you could float the columns right this would reverse the order you put them on the screen.

```
 .floatRight
    {
        float: right;
    }

<div class="floatRight">1</div>
<div class="floatRight">2,</div>
```

This will display as 2,1

Or in JQuery take a look at this question:

[Reverse sort divs using CSS or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062630/reverse-sort-divs-using-css-or-jquery)