# Rearrange Positions Purely by CSS

Tags: css, html, positioning

I've been Googling and looking for a way to position elements with CSS, but I'm having trouble solving a problem.

A good example of what I'm trying to do is:

I have two divs,

```
<div class="A"></div>
<div class="B"></div>
```

I want to use CSS to display div class B *above* div class A.
My question is: Is it possible to use solely CSS to display B on top of A without changing the HTML? Or is the only way to display B on top of A to put the div HTML for B above that of A?

Comment: If the content of `B` isn't a fixed size, it's not possible. So is it?

Comment: Its not possible you can use jquery or javascript to get this

Comment: The content is just some text. A date or a title.
Are you asking if B has a CSS specified height and width?

Comment: @Dinesh: Could you help me with a link or an example I can look at to do this?

Comment: Yes. If `B` has a specified height you can do something like has been answered below. Set `B` to `top: 0px;` and `A` to `top: Xpx;` Where X is ofcourse the height of the content in `B`.

Comment: I see the exact problem you brought up, @Henrik.
I did indeed have variable-length contents for the divs so I ended up JavaScripting the content height and inserting CSS rules to position A and B.
Thank you for pointing that out -- it helped me recognize that problem and keep working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a css like this

```
.A,.B{
width: 48%;
float: right;
}

.A {
background-color: #ffa;
}

.B{
background-color: #0f0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MmFsM/1/) See this for [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062630/reverse-sort-divs-using-css-or-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

here is your answer,

> .a, .b {
>       position: absolute;
>
> ```
> }
> .a {
> top:50px;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it depends on what are you trying to achieve. And still the best way will be to simply put the B div in front. 
The other way is with positioning.
position:absolute on both will work fine, but you need to know the exact width and height of the elements. If for example both has height: 50px and width: 50px your code will look like that:

```
.a {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
position:absolute; 
top: 50px;
left: 0;
}

.b {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
position: absolute; 
top: 0px;
left: 0;
}
```

The other way is with margin minus for element B.

```
.a {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
margin-top: 50px;
}

.b {
margin-top: -100px;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
.B{

margin-top:-50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is :

```
#wrapper { 
     position: relative; 
     }

    #firstDiv { 
     position: absolute; 
     height: 100px; 
     top: 110px; 
     }

    #secondDiv { 
     position: absolute; 
     height: 100px; 
     top: 0; 
     }
```

[For more ways try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220273/css-positioning-div-above-another-div-when-not-in-that-order-in-the-html)